# QtWebKit not found by Quantum GIS (qgis) software - OpenLayers Plugin

Tags: xubuntu, qt, qt4, qgis

I have Yakkety installed on my PC.

I have installed Quantum GIS 2.18 using the installation process described in the link https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. I used the debian method.

I am trying to use the OpenLayers Plugin, which is trusted by the QGIS S/W.

While enabling the plugin, it screams that it requires QtWebKit, which although installed on the PC, is not found by QGIS. Apparently QtWebKit (as required by QGIS) is for QT4, but Yakkety is on Qt5.

What is the solution?

Comment: Did you try with QtWebEngine instead? QtWebKit doesn't exist anymore on Qt 5 as you said.